# Basis for the set of diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be the set of all diagonal matrices. How can we calculate it's basis and dimension? I am not really good at it. Can you help me with this, so thus I will have some picture.

Comment: Hint: for $k$ between $1$ and $n$, consider those matrices $\mathcal{A}$ which are $0$ except at $\mathcal{A}_{k,k}$ where they are $1$.

Comment: The space of diagonal $n \times n$ matrices has dimension $n$, with basis the $E_{11},E_{22}, \cdots E_{nn}$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
0&a_2&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&a_3 &\cdots &0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots &a_n
\end{bmatrix}=
a_1
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0 &\cdots &0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots &0
\end{bmatrix}+
a_2
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&\cdots &0\\
0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0 &\cdots &0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots &0
\end{bmatrix}+
a_3
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&\cdots &0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&1 &\cdots &0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots &0
\end{bmatrix}+
\cdots+
a_n
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&\cdots &0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
0&0&0 &\cdots &0\\
\cdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots &1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Do you know a basis for the vector space of all matrices of a fixed size? The basis for $n \times n$ matrices is the set of matrices having exactly one entry equal to $1$ and all the rest equal to zero.  There are $n^2$ such matrices.  Do you see why?  Once you understand this, consider restricting your attention to the diagonal matrices in this basis.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good hint for these problems: intuitively, the dimension of a vector space is the number of "coordinates" (i.e. scalars) required to describe each point uniquely.

Surely, then, it makes sense to describe the $n \times n$ diagonal matrices using $n$ coordinates.  Indeed, the "common-sense" approach corresponds to using the basis
$$
\pmatrix{1\\&0\\&&0\\ && & \ddots \\ && & & 0}, \quad \pmatrix{0\\&1\\&&0\\&&&\ddots \\&&&&0}, \dots
$$