# Find basis of specific subspace of vector space $V = M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $W$ be the subspace of vector space $V = M_2(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of the diagonal matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, where $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices over field $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is to find the basis of quotient space $V/W$.

Quotient space can be stated as follows: 
Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. The set $V /W$ is the set defined by

$V /W = \{v + W : v\in V\}$

That is, $V /W$ is the collection of cosets of $W$ in $V$. It seems to me that cosets in the given problem are sets consisting of upper and lower triangular matrices. Am i correct?  How to solve this problem mathematically. What should be my approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $\textsf W$ be a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $\textsf V$. If $\{ w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ is a basis for $\textsf W$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_k,w_{k+1},w_{k+2}\dots,w_n\}$ an extension of this basis to a basis for the whole space $\textsf V$, then
$$\{w_{k+1}+\textsf{W}, w_{k+2}+\textsf{W}, \dots, w_n+\textsf{W}\}$$
form a basis for the quotient space $\textsf{V}/\textsf{W}$.

Comment: I understand this result. But unable to proceed further. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint. I am just confused with whether element $(0~ 1; 1 ~0)$ forms basis for W or not?

Comment: In this link space of diagonal matrices have dimension n is mentioned https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568413/basis-for-the-set-of-diagonal-matrices

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I confused diagonal matrices with symmetric matrices. Right, since every diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} \in \textsf W$ can be writen as $$\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ a basis for $\textsf{W}$ is the set $$\gamma = \bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \bigg\}$$

Comment: So, if we add the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\gamma$ we obtain a basis for $\textsf{V}$, right? It follows that a basis for the quotient space is the set $$\bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + \textsf{W}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + \textsf{W} \bigg\}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood completely.